# Contributions to a GitHub repository not showing in my Careers profile

Tags: bug, jobs, github

I have contributed some code to [Idris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_%28programming_language%29), but that is hidden in my Careers profile. It says it couldn't find any commits. How come?

Comment: Are you talking about your Stack Overflow Careers profile?

Comment: Yes. I tried adding the repo manually too. Doesn't show up, although this time it tells me that it's fetching info from github.

Comment: It wasn't clear at all what you were talking about initially, someone even voted to close as off-topic since it didn't look like a Stack Exchange issue. Being a bit more descriptive next time wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Ok, the cluster of sites is really confusing. I clicked the support link in stack overflow careers and stack exchange came up. I assumed it's all linked just like the google apps so mentioning the "Careers" profile will be enough. I am still not sure what I am expected to do. Did I ask in the wrong place? Should I do something else? Apologies for my sheer incompetence.

Comment: You're in the right place. The initial "problem" was that you didn't mention your Careers profile. You talked about "a profile". This is indeed the right site for support questions regarding Careers, but it is not dedicated to Careers only, and gets quite a lot of completely random/off-topic posts. Just make sure you mention careers next time and add the tag.

Comment: Thanks Mat :) So I will consider this issue reported.